# Gremlin query which only returns vertices having edges

Tags: gremlin

Is there a more efficient way of returning the id of the first 100 vertices which have edges and do not have a specific property?

```
g.V()
 .filter(hasNot("SOME_PROPERTY").bothE())
 .limit(100)
 .id()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can write that in a much more optimal fashion. That traversal will only be as fast as the the underlying graphs ability to optimize the absence of a property which typically isn't that fast. It's generally treated as a global operation that has to iterate every vertex in the graph (or until it finds 100 matches) and I don't think that any graph allows indices that can help in this sort of case.

If this traversal is meant to be a real-time traversal (OLTP) then you should probably consider defaulting that "SOME_PROPERTY" so that it can be indexed in some way to detect negative values or if it is more of an administrative traversal (e.g. detecting bad data to clean up) (OLAP) then you should probably execute that traversal with Gremlin Spark.

Comment: Currently "SOME_PROPERTY" is set to 1 under specific conditions, otherwise the property is not added to the vertices. I assume that checking for the value of the property would not really be any faster. e.g.  `g.V().filter(not(has("SOME_PROPERTY",P.eq(1))))...`
Also, the underlying db we are using is AWS Neptune, which as far as I know, doesn't allow for any additional indexing.

Comment: Without an index I think you would see the same performance because you would still have to iterate all the vertices to find that value of 1. If you index that value it could be faster but it sounds like the index would have low selectivity so it would return a lot of vertices which could be costly to iterate depending on how many there were.

Comment: After running through some tests at "scale" (meaning around 92 million vertices), it seems like it is more efficient to split those two out of the filter. `g.V().hasNot("SOME_PROPERTY").filter(bothE()).limit(100).id()`. It also looks like the `.filter(bothE())` is pretty expensive.

Comment: hmm `bothE()` shouldn't be that expensive for `filter()` as you only need 1 for the filter to pass. i'm not completely familiar with Neptune's internals though. Perhaps Neptune would be happier to complete that faster if you gave it a hint that you only wanted one like, `filter(bothE().limit(1))`?